# C# How to implement Threading or BackgroundWorker tasks

Tags: c#, multithreading, treeview, progress-bar, backgroundworker

I can't seem to figure out how to use either the threading or Backgroundworker task.  My problem is that I am loading a large XML file into a TreeView and would like to display a progress bar while doing so.  The issue right now is that the app freezes when it's loading and says the app is non-responsive.

Threading / Background worker tasks is new to me so I am not exactly sure how to make this work.

First we will start with my button to get the user details

So we get the users's details and call CreateXML for the user detail object.  So we have the XML in one big string called strXML.  Then I call dom.LoadXml to load xml sting into the dom object.  Then we initialize the tree view control and add the nodes etc.

So during this whole process the app hangs and indicates that it's not responding while it's busy churning thought the XML and creating it into a treeview.   I want to put in a progress bar so the end user see's that something is actually going on and they don't think the app just died on them.

How would i implement some sort of progress bar with a thread or back ground worker?

Please just don't redirect me to link after link because that never really works for me.

Thanks

Comment: Your program is slow because it was poorly designed.  You expect your user to claw through *thousands* of treeview nodes to find the needle in the haystack back.  No human can do this, they give up after 50.  Just look how Google displays a million hits for a simple query.  So a simple approach is to display only up to 50 nodes.  With a button that displays the next 50.  Now the program is not slow anymore.

Comment: my post was about how to create a progress bar with a background worker task or using threading..

Comment: Is it the creation of the XML and DOM that is slow, or the populating of the tree view control? If the latter then switching to a background thread won't help you as the contents of the tree view control can only be modified on the UI thread anyway.

Comment: It's the creation of the tree view.  I just need to implement some sort of progress bar.  Without the progress bar it takes about 30 seconds to complete.  I just need some sort of UI indicator for the end user so they don't think the app is no longer responding.

Comment: @user1158745 Then as I said in my previous comment switching to a background process won't help you here. However, a 30s update for a `TreeView` seems a bit extreme. Are there any ways you could optimise your tree view update code to make it faster? I would concentrate on that first, or do as @HansPassant says and deal with it in smaller blocks of items.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to implement multi-threading which then I was able to achieve the progress bar moving while the data was being loaded.  Sometimes people need to wait for data to be loaded and a simple indicator is all that's needed so users know the app is working.